# .Net Runtime version 2.0 Fatal Execution Engine Error

Tags: asp.net, .net

Windows version: Windows Server version 6.0(Build 6002: Service Pack 2) / Windows Server 2008 Enterprise without Hyper-V

.Net runtime version:.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.4234

I'm running ASP.net 2.0 application. The application runs fine in a VM environment. And I keep getting various Fatal Execution Engine Error on if I run the application in testing machine.

Both VM and actual testing machine has the same windows and .net runtime version as specificed above. The testing machines has 48 cores.

Typical error I received:

.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.4234 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7069CBDE) (80131506)

Comment: Without seeing at least *some* code, this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: I had a quick Google, apparently this type of error is caused by corruption in the managed heap. It's rare that the CLR corrupts itself, the most likely culprits are bad P/Invoke signatures and generally doing things you're not meant to (native code scribbling over memory).

Answer (score 1):

I have found my problem.

This is the answer from Microsoft:

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2276255

However, you have to apply both workaround to solve this issue